# Generic struct that accepts any struct

Tags: go

How to make a generic struct that accepts any struct?

```
package model

type model struct {
    m *interface{}
}

func (m *model) Select(){
    
}

type (
    field struct {
        table   string
        field   string
    }
    fields  map[string]field
)

type User struct {
    schema      string
    fields      fields
}

func NewUser() *interface{} {
    model_user := &User{
        schema: "main",
        
        fields: fields{
            "id":           field{"user","id"},
            "client_id":    field{"user","client_id"},
            "email":        field{"user","email"},
        },
    }
    return model(model_user)
}
```

main

```
NewUser()
```

error

```
cannot convert model_user (variable of type *User) to type model
```

Comment: Don't use pointer to interface. That's almost never what you want. https://go.dev/play/p/jqfBhSYPu63

Comment: No. Structs are concrete types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As defined the `model` struct appears to exist to add (or attempt to add) a `Select()` function to the value contained within the model.

i.e. you appear to want some type that provides for the ability to call `Select()` and have that perform some operation on a value of any arbitrary type (presumably with some form of type switch in the `Select()` implementation).

If so then you may be better off simply using an `interface` directly and eliminating the `model` middle-man:

```
type Selectable interface {
  Select()
}

type User struct {
  //...
}

func (u *User) Select() {
   // implement Select as appropriate for the User type
}

func NewUser() *User {
  return &User{
     // ...
  }
}

func Select(s Selectable) {
   s.Select()
}

func main() {
   u := NewUser()
   Select(u)
}
```

You will observe that the `Select(Selectable)` function is superfluous (you could simply call `u.Select()` directly; it is provided only to illustrate that a value of any type may be used where a `Selectable` is required, provided that the type implements the `Selectable` interface.

`interfaces` in GoLang provide duck-typing - if a type implements the contract of an interface then it implements that interface, even when that concrete type has no prior knowledge of any formal interface definition.  i.e. "if it looks like a duck and quacks like a duck, it's a duck".

If the intent is to remove the logic of `Select()ing` from the `User` type (or other types) and isolate this in a separate "selector" then this may be achieved again by removing the `model` intermediary and simply implementing a func that performs a type-switch:

```golang
func Select(v any) error {
   switch v := v.(type) {
      case *User:
         // ... implement for *User or call some private fn which encapsulates this behaviour
      default:
          return errors.New("value cannot be Select()ed")
    }
}
```